# how to make if and else condition in android for setOnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i want to make an if else condition for setOnClickListener. how should i do it? the code below is working correctly. its just that i would like to make a condition. if user enter numbers more than 10000, i want the app to make a pop up alert to tell user to edit the number so that it will not exceed 10000. please help me on how to do it. below is the code in java.

```
package com.example.mobilecatering;

public class mcpakej1 extends Activity  {

    private EditText phone;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mcpakej1);

        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guest);
        phone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Maximum 10000 only.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.show();
            }
        });

        public void goReceipt(View v)  {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), doReceipt.class);
            intent.putExtra("phone", phone.getText().toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent,0); 
        }
    }
}
```

this is the xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView50"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Number of guest(s)"/>

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/guest"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"   
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:hint="Enter number 1 to 10 000 only." />
        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/gobutton"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/homebtn"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homebtn"
    android:background="@drawable/gobutton"
    android:onClick="goReceipt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

User have to enter number in the EditText. after that when they click on GoButton to move to next page. if they enter number more than 10000, and they click on gobutton afterwards, the app suppose make an alert message for user and resume to the edittext after user click ok. how am i suppose to do that? help me please.

any helps is appreciated.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void goReceipt(View v) 
 {
    try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.guest)).getText().toString());
            if (number > 50 && number <= 10000) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), doReceipt.class);
                intent.putExtra("phone", phone.getText().toString());
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            } else {
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Maximum 10000 only.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.show();
            } 
    } catch (Exception ex) {}

 }
```

Comment: what should i put in the catch condition?

Comment: @CikHusna - whatever you want. You can leave it empty or show toast: Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You entered NOT number",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: the parseInt become error. it said that The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)

Comment: @CikHusna Updated my answer, please check. It should help.

Comment: i have tried your code. but when i click on proceed button without entering the number, the app stop unexpectedly.

Comment: Just ran this code - it works fine, exception is handling by catch block. If the error is still happening - provide a Stacktrace, please. Thx.

Comment: sorry sir. i had tried your code, but nothing happen to the apps. no error, no stop unexpectedly. what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

you should do something like this

```
phone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (Integer.ParseInt(phone.getText().toString()) > 10000) {
                  Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Maximum 10000 only.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   msg.show();
                 } else {
                    // do something else
                 }
           } catch(Exception e) {
                // given text is not number
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Surround the IF/ELSE with `try... catch block` as this could generate an exception. Also add `trim()` to the string incase of any additional space. Also would recommend using `Double` as the value expected is currency

Comment: @codePG that advice is (partly) **wrong**. One should always strive to keep try-catch blocks' scopes to a minimum. At "best" I'd surround the `Toast.makeText()` call with a try...catch block.

Comment: what should i state in catch condition?

Comment: you should probably tell the user that he/she must enter numeric value in `EditText` and if my answer solved your problem, please accept it! :)

Answer (score 0):

here is solution:

```
String str = phone.getText().toString();
if(Integer.parseInt(str) > 10000) {
   Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Maximum 10000 only.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   msg.show();
} else {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: the if statement will determine the number right? if more than 10000 is enter, then, the app will stop unexpectedly or resume for user to enter the number again?

Comment: Add snippet to onClick(View v) function inside button listener. Toast will shown always when user enters number more than 10000 and press button. After entering correct number and pressing button //your code will execute.

Answer (score 0):

> Do like this,

```
btnFinalAns.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (edtFinalPolishRate.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                    a1.setMessage("FinalPolishRate is Empty");
                    edtFinalPolishRate.requestFocus();
}else{
a1.setMessage("MarketRate is Empty");
                    edtMarketRate.requestFocus();
}}};
```

Comment: can u explain what is a1?